# Error insert from CSV when last row has less columns

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, temp-tables

I'm trying to bulk insert a table with the code below:

```
DROP TABLE #temp_FeirasLivres

CREATE TABLE #temp_FeirasLivres
(
ID INT null,
LONG BIGINT null,
LAT  BIGINT null,
SETCENS BIGINT null,
AREAP BIGINT null,
CODDIST INT null,
DISTRITO NVARCHAR(100) null,
CODSUBPREF INT null,
SUBPREFE NVARCHAR(200) null,
REGIAO5 NVARCHAR(200) null,
REGIAO8 NVARCHAR(200) null,
NOME_FEIRA NVARCHAR(200) null,
REGISTRO NVARCHAR(50) null,
LOGRADOURO NVARCHAR(100) null,
NUMERO NVARCHAR(200) null default('S/N'),
BAIRRO NVARCHAR(50) null default(''),
REFERENCIA NVARCHAR(100) null
)


BULK INSERT #temp_FeirasLivres
FROM 'DEINFO_AB_FEIRASLIVRES_2014.csv'
WITH
(
FORMAT = 'CSV',
FirstRow = 1
);
```

The content of file has 880 rows, but I'll show here enough to validate what I'm saying:

> 879,-46610849,-23609187,355030827000078,3550308005044,27,CURSINO,13,IPIRANGA,Sul,Sul 1,CERRACAO,4025-8,RUA LINO GUEDES,109.000000,MOINHO VELHO,ALTURA DA VERGUEIRO 7450
> 880,-46450426,-23602582,355030833000022,3550308005274,32,IGUATEMI,30,SAO MATEUS,Leste,Leste 2,JD.BOA ESPERANCA,5171-3,RUA IGUPIARA,S/N,JD BOA ESPERANCA

The error is about the last row has fewer columns than the other rows (there is no, after the previous value).

If I put a "," after BOA ESPERANCA, it works, but I want to know if there is anything I can do on source to save time from always opening and fixing the CSV file.

PS: The last row has a line breaker after it, and I've tried with rowterminator on bulk options, but can try again.

Comment: Where is the file actually sourced from? Do you have access to the export mechanism or is it generated for you? If the latter, tell whoever is responsible to fix it. The fact that a column simply goes missing seems very odd, and surely hints at a bug/coding error somewhere. Normally, if a column does not contain data, a `NULL` value would be supplied (or simply a repetition of the column separator without any data between).

Comment: The file comes from a source over which I don´t have any control or relation. It's a governmental list of cities' Fairs. I'm pretty sure the government will not care about it.
In other rows, if the last column is null (or the row has fewer columns than the schema), it inserts nulls. The problem is the last row only. The SQL cannot detect the row is ended because there isn't another row.

Comment: SQL Server expects the file to be well formed; that means that it has to have the *same* amount of columns in every row. if the file is malformed (which is appears to be), you'll need to fix the file first, and then `BULK INSERT` it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you wanna make an answer with your comment so I can close it.
I hope a better way exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larnu saids in comments:

> SQL Server expects the file to be well formed; that means that it has to have the same amount of columns in every row. if the file is malformed (which is appears to be), you'll need to fix the file first, and then BULK INSERT it.

So, it's the best answer.